# Load image from viewmodel into view with Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I'm trying to let the user load an image in the view.

My main view:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestApplication.Views.MainView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Image
            Grid.Column="0"
            Stretch="Uniform"
            x:Name="Preview">
            <Image.Source>
                <BitmapImage UriSource="pack://application:,,,/Resources/placeholder.jpg" />
            </Image.Source>
        </Image>

        <ContentControl
            Grid.Column="1"
            x:Name="ImageManagement" />

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

My main viewmodel:

```
namespace TestApplication.ViewModels
{
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using Caliburn.Micro;
    using PropertyChanged;
    using TestApplication.Events;

    [ImplementPropertyChanged]
    [Export(typeof(MainViewModel))]
    public class MainViewModel : PropertyChangedBase, IHandle<FileSelectedEvent>
    {
        private readonly IEventAggregator events;

        [ImportingConstructor]
        public MainViewModel(IEventAggregator events)
        {
            this.events = events;
            this.events.Subscribe(this);

            this.ImageManagement = new ImageManagementViewModel(events);
        }

        public ImageManagementViewModel ImageManagement { get; set; }

        public Image Preview { get; set; }

        public void Handle(FileSelectedEvent message)
        {
            // load the selected image
        }
    }
}
```

The image placeholder isn't displayed, and snoop doesn't even see it.

Furthermore, when loading an image by instantiating a `BitmapImage` and setting it to the `Preview.Source` in the `Handle` method... The `Preview` property is null, and if I initialize it first, it's never displayed either.

The PropertyChanged is handled through Fody.

Comment: Placeholder is probably an invalid uri.  Can't debug that for you. Preview isn't bound to anything in the code you included, so I'm not sure how this magic is supposed to work...

Comment: the default convention for Image is on the Source property and is triggered by Loaded. I would wager that you probably need to make Image a URI or string value,  not an actual Image control.

Comment: I think @Will is right with respect to the pack uri, I don't think you need it to begin with.  Just set the Source to the ```<Image x:Name="Preview" Fill="Uniform" Source="/Resources/placeholder.jpg" />``` once a property change is triggered it should bind by convention.

Comment: Will: I'm using Caliburn.Micro, which uses [name-based conventions](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Basic%20Configuration%2c%20Actions%20and%20Conventions&referringTitle=Documentation). mvermef: Thanks, I did not think to look into different binding conventions for different controls. I'll check it out. For the BitmapImage as Source, I found it on SO, but that was not my first try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Will and @mvermef, I found my answer.

The placeholder URL was not invalid, but it does work without the `pack://` part. I like it, though, because then it's explicit that it's a resource and not a file.

The real problem was that, indeed, Caliburn.Micro wasn't actually binding to the control, but to the `Source` property. Switching to this solved the issue:

```
    <Image
        Grid.Column="0"
        Stretch="Uniform"
        Source="{Binding PreviewUrl}" />
```

and the viewmodel:

```
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public MainViewModel(IEventAggregator events)
    {
        this.events = events;
        this.events.Subscribe(this);

        this.ImageManagement = new ImageManagementViewModel(events);
        this.PreviewUrl = "pack://application:,,,/Resources/placeholder.jpg";
    }

    public String PreviewUrl { get; set; }

    public void Handle(FileSelectedEvent message)
    {
        this.PreviewUrl = message.FilePath;
    }
```